# Add a remote image programmatically to media module with rules

Tags: media, uri

I use rules and the media module and would like to add remote images
like http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/6/61/Weingarten_Zentrum1.jpg
programmatically with php.

I found this post but I still have no idea what exactly to do..
[How to programmatically add image from external URL using media module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13340/how-to-programmatically-add-image-from-external-url-using-media-module)

Comment: I can't get the idea about your question....Can You Please Elaborate..
What i Understood is that you want to fetch a image form other website to your drupal website by changing "src" attribute of img tag

Comment: if Media module is not your project neccessity you van use ckeditor for this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Drupal Answers. May you edit your question to explain what exactly you didn't understand in the answers given for the other question? Without that information, this question is a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: ok, I got it:
If you have an url of an image and you would like to insert into with php for the media module, it works like this:
`code`
    $image = file_get_contents($urlToImage); 
    $file = file_save_data($image,'public://'.$imageName,FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    $node-> field_dorfbild['und'][0] = array('fid'=>$file->fid, 'display'=>1);`code`